# Ошибка при запуске vbs скрипта через планировщик задач

Tags: vbscript, планировщик-задач

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке запустить vbs скрипт через планировщик выдает следующую ошибку (картинка):
Сам VBS отдельно без планировщика запускается и отрабатывает.
Проблема на одном из ПК, на других работает.
Параметры запуска в планировщике:
Программа или сценарий - wscript.exe
Аргумент - "ПУТЬ ДО СКРИПТА\Test_Script.vbs"

Comment: Небось нет прав прочитать скрипт в каталоге..

Comment: Все права есть, настройки аналогичные с другими ПК.

Comment: У какой учётной записи "все права есть"? от имени кого выполняется скрипт в планировщике? Я уж не говорю о том, что на показанном скрине явно слеплены вместе два пути...